# Why is the eigenwave function not periodic in the lattice?

Tags: wavefunction, solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model

There is such an expression in the Bloch wave:
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R}_n) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{R}_n} \psi( \mathbf{r} ) 
$$
Where $\mathbf{R}_n = n_1 \mathbf{a}_1 + n_2 \mathbf{a}_2 + n_3 \mathbf{a}_3$, $\mathbf{a}$ is the basis vector of the unit cell.
At the same time, in the lattice, for any function$f(\mathbf{r})$, we have:
$$
f(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}_n) = f(\mathbf{r})
$$
Isn't this contradictory, shouldn't $\psi$ be an arbitrary function $f$?
And it is also described in the Born–von Karman boundary condition.

Comment: @hft In the lattice, every unit cell is all the same, so this expression is true. Is this not true?

Comment: It’s hard to imagine what you mean here. $f(\mathbf r)=\mathbf r$ is a function and it clearly doesn’t have the property you speak of. Why would this be true? In free space, every point is “the same” (in the same sense that in a lattice, every lattice point is the same) but that obviously doesn’t mean that every function is constant, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At the same time, in the lattice, for any function $f(\mathbf{r})$, we have:
> $$
> f(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}_n) = f(\mathbf{r})
> $$

No. This is not true. Why would this be true for "any function" in a lattice? (It is not.)

> Isn't this contradictory, shouldn't $\psi$ be an arbitrary function $f$?

Yes, what **you** wrote is contradictory, but what you wrote also is not true.

---

I think what you are trying to get at is that a *Bloch function* can be written in the form:
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{r}}u(\mathbf{r})\;,
$$
where the function $u$ is periodic:
$$
u(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}_n) = u(\mathbf{r})\;.
$$

Just because the function $u$ is periodic does not mean every function you ever consider is periodic. For example, the Bloch function clearly is not periodic (it changes by a phase $e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}_n}$).

---

**Update to address comments and further explain:**

The quantity in a lattice that is *known* to be periodic is the *potential*:
$$
V_{lattice}(\vec r + \vec R_n) = V_{lattice}(\vec r)\;,
$$
but this does not mean that the **solutions** to the Schrödinger equation for this potential have this same periodicity.

The above statement can be rephrased as: the symmetry of the potential (in this case the periodicity) is not necessarily a symmetry of the solutions to the Schrödinger equation for that potential.

By analogy, consider the hydrogen atom. The hydrogen atom *potential* is spherically symmetric, but the solutions are not necessarily spherically symmetric. Only the "s-wave" solutions are spherically symmetric. The "p-wave" and higher angular momentum solutions are not spherically symmetric. The symmetry is still important because the solutions transform according to irreducible representations of the group (e.g., the $Y_{\ell m}$ for a spherical potential).

Similarly, the solutions to the Schrödinger equation in a periodic potential are *not necessarily* periodic in the same way. Like the "s-wave" in hydrogen, we have one type of solution that has the same symmetry (the $k=0$ solutions). But the vast majority of solutions are not periodic. But in the same way we can use group theory to come up with the labels (the $\vec k$ is similar to the $\ell m$ label in hydrogen in this regard).

Comment: Yes, there are some mistakes in my writing, but I still don't understand why$f(\mathbf{r}) =f(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}_n)$ is not ture.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you get it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know bloch can be written as a plane wave with periodic function grades. so why $u(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R}_n) = u(\mathbf{r})$, but $\psi(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{R}_n) \ne \psi (\mathbf{r})$ , How to tell when a function is equal and when it is not equal.Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer. In general there is no way. But I've explained further what is known to be periodic and what is known to be not periodic and why. @ZhaoDazhuang